# How to stop and restart a CountDown timer

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, activity-lifecycle

I am aware that timer.cancel() is used to stop a countdown timer I am also aware that once the activity is going into the background, it calls the method

```
protected void onPause();
```

and when it is about to come to foreground, it call the method

```
protected void onResume();
```

I have been having some difficulty with storing the value of the countdown timer while the activity is going to the background and continuing the timer immediately the activity comes to view again. See what I have tried

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  

   if (mCountDownTimer != null){

       mCountDownTimer.cancel();
       mCountDownTimer = null;

       SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(TIME_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
       editor.putString("time", mTextField.getText().toString()).commit();
   }}
```

Then this :

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 


    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(TIME_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String prefString = sharedPrefs.getString("time", null);

    if (prefString != null) {

        mTextField.setText(prefString);
        countdown(prefString, sec);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefToDel = context.getSharedPreferences(TIME_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPrefToDel.edit().clear().commit();

    }

}
```

This is my countdown method:

```
    public void countdown(final String theTime, final long longVal) {

    final int red = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
    mTextField = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countdown);

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(longVal, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText(theTime);

            if ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) < 60) {
                if (millisUntilFinished / 1000 < 10) {
                    mTextField.setTextColor(red);
                    mTextField.setText("00:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                } else
                    mTextField.setText("00:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }
            if ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) >= 60 && (millisUntilFinished / 1000) < 120) {

                if (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - 60) < 10) {
                    mTextField.setText("01:0" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - 60));

                } else
                    mTextField.setText("01:" + ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - 60));

            }

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("00:00");

        }
    }.start();

}
```

The problem is that whenever the application comes back from the background, the timer starts showing multiple countdowns. What exactly do I need to do?

Comment: you can use chronometer instead

Comment: Unfortunately, it requires minSDKversion 24 to able to perform countDown(true) but I need to target as low as 14. Any other suggestion? @KrishnaMeena

Comment: in chronometer case you need to save time value in a list or variable and chronometer gives you events for every second so in that increase or decrease your time value and show that